# emacs set real time checks on the file

Tags: emacs

## Circumstance

As I am testing some programs on the command line and the output is very long, I try to store the output in a file and renew it from time to time. However, the emacs is not checking for renewment. So I need to reopen the file repeatedly.

## Quesion

### emacs

I wander if there are good modes or settings for doing that.

### Others

If not, I wander whether there are good text viewing tools to use to solve my problem.

Thanks a lot ;P

Answer (score 2):

You can use `M-x auto-revert-mode` - or `M-x auto-revert-tail-mode`, if you're only appending to the file.